# Convert this file into dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary

I have looked around on Stackoverflow but could but could not find it discussed here. I have a list that I want to convert into dictionary.

```
3
banana
apple
orange
5.00E-2
1
7.02E-4
1.00E-4
4
5.13E-4
-5.76E-2
8
7.23E-8
-6.12E-9
4
5.02E
```

The number 3 is the number of keys. The next 3 strings are the key-names. And the next 3 values are the first elements of the list....and so on . For example I would get:

```
  mydict['banana']=[ 5.00E-2, 1.00E-4, -5.76E-2, -6.12E-9]
  mydict['apple'] =[1,           4,       8,        4]
  mydict['orange']=[ 7.02E-4, 5.13E-4,  7.23E-8,   np.nan ]
```

Notice that the last element is not complete and is just "5.02E" and must be replaced by numpy.nan. Furthermore, the number of elements in each list must be the same and missing values should be numpy.nan.  This is a python 2.7.x question.

So my question is that I am looking for the best way of creating the dictionary. How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
num = mylist[0]
mydict = {}
for i in range(num):
    mydict[mylist[i + 1]] = mylist[i + 1 + num::num]
```

or if you prefer one-liners,

```
mydict = {mylist[i + 1]:mylist[num + i + 1::num] for i in range(mylist[0])}
```

Note that this does not replace missing items with `numpy.nan`; that would be something like

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import numpy as np

num      = mylist[0]
labels   = mylist[1:num + 1]
num_cols = (len(mylist) - 2) // num
cols     = (mylist[1 + c*num::num] for c in range(1, num_cols + 2))
rows     = izip_longest(*cols, fillvalue=np.nan)

mydict = dict(zip(labels, rows))
```

Comment: @no_name I like your idea. Could you expand on it in a little more detail?

Comment: the first 'num' values are the key names. Wouldn't your answer create a dict of dicts?

Comment: @CorruptedStack, the dict comprehension idea was implemented in the answer above, I think this answer works for your code... no?

Comment: @no_name I think you were editing the answer as I was reading it ha ha ha

Comment: Your one liner did a better work than your result using itertools. But I guess I must have tested your answer before you even completed it

Answer (score 0):

I think, [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) + [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) may be useful here:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import cycle, izip, count, repeat

result = defaultdict(list)

with open(path) as fp:
    num = int(next(fp))
    idx = 0

    # create infinite loop of repeating keys to match them with the values:
    keys = cycle([next(fp).strip() for _ in range(num)])

    for k, v, c in izip(keys, fp, count()):
        result[k].append(np.float(v))

    if (c + 1) % num: # need to populate with nans
        result[k].extend(repeat(np.nan, num - (c + 1) % num))
```

Comment: Did you mean to indent the last if statement. Yes or no?

Comment: @CorruptedStack indented as I meant, after the `for`-loop is finished, we may need to complete the list for the last key.

Comment: I tried to test your code. I am having problems with "keys = cycle(next(f).strip() for f in range(num))". Is there some typo on that line? I get the error "TypeError: int object is not an iterator"

Comment: @CorruptedStack I fixed that line, sorry. The loop also should be in `[ ]` to eliminate the laziness.

Comment: @CorruptedStack That said, the one-liner above is a better solution :)